# Error on accessing property of defined object in React when state is set in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to figure out how to pass props to a component matching a certain route. As you can see from the code below, every time a user hits `/items/:id` I get the id from the url and hopefully get the right item accessing the array using that id.

```
<Route exact path="/items/:id" render={(props) => {
    let itemId = parseInt(props.location.pathname.replace('/items/', ''));
       console.log(this.state.items[itemId].description);
       return <ItemDetail item={this.state.items[itemId]} />;
```

The problem is if I run this code, React will crash returning an angry red `cannot read property description of undefined`, but — and that's where I get totally confused — if I try to log `this.state.items[itemId]` I get to see the full object in the console. Naturally the exact same thing happens if I pass `item` as a prop and try to get the description out of it from the child component `ItemDetail`.

You need to now I am currently setting the data in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method with a simple

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      items: data
    });
  }
```

and React breaks but if I change that to the soon to be deprecated `componentWillMount` the application runs as it should and I don't understand why. If state has been set after mounting and I know for a fact that the item exists in the array because I can log it, why can't I read the properties inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since seem to be synchronously setting state in `componentDidMount`, you can safely move it to constructor to avoid the error

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         items: data
     }
}
```

If the data is coming from an API call then you would need to make that API call in `componentDidMount` and set the state on onsuccess or onerror callback and provide a conditional check when using the state value in render like

```
return <ItemDetail item={this.state.items? this.state.items[itemId] : {}} />;
```

or show loading till the API call is a success

```
render() {
   if(!this.state.items) {
       return <div>Loading...</div>
   }
   return <Route exact path="/items/:id" render={(props) => {
    let itemId = parseInt(props.location.pathname.replace('/items/', ''));
       console.log(this.state.items[itemId].description);
       return <ItemDetail item={this.state.items[itemId]} />;
}
```

Comment: @haunted85 You need to handle the case where there's no data to display. Show a "Loading..." message or something similar while your component waits for the data.

Comment: @RossAllen there are multiple ways to handle it, it depends on OP use case. OP can either show a loading in the parent or in ItemDetails. But sure a way to handle it is loading

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you for your solution! But still I was wondering, how come I can read an object from state just fine but I am not able to access its properties?

Comment: That is because this.state is defined and hence you can read `this.state.items` which gives you undefined, and now when you try, `this.state.items[itemId]` its essentially `undefined[itemId]` which isn't valid and hence you get an error